# Remove repeating header rows CSV in BASH

Tags: bash

I concatenated 11 csv files in one file= test.csv

The test.csv file looks the following:

```
EMAIL_MD5_HASH_
12345
45678
56789
65478
EMAIL_MD5_HASH_
65738
64738
92827
35658
EMAIL_MD5_HASH_
08978
34546
98765
89076
EMAIL_MD5_HASH_
09875
12564
09876
```

How do remove the repeating headers using BASH in mac? I want my o/p file as, test.csv

```
EMAIL_MD5_HASH_
12345
45678
56789
65478
65738
64738
92827
35658
08978
34546
98765
89076
09875
09874
```

The file has 8.3 MM records. Excel doesn't like or else I would have done a find and replace. All I want to remove is the repeating headers values

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to print the first row (your initial header) and then print each remaining row that starts with a number using `awk`, e.g.

```
awk 'FNR == 1; FNR > 1 && /^[0-9]/' file
```

Where

- `FNR == 1` uses the default print operation to output the first line;
- `FNR > 1 && /^[0-9]/` for all *File Records Numbers* (lines) greater than one and starting with a digit, output using the default print operation.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example in `file` you would get:

```
$ awk 'FNR == 1; FNR > 1 && /^[0-9]/' file
EMAIL_MD5_HASH_
12345
45678
56789
65478
65738
64738
92827
35658
08978
34546
98765
89076
09875
12564
09876
```

Let me know if that is what you intended. So long as it is a plain text file with `'\n'` line endings, `awk` should handle 8.3M records in little more than a second.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your Input_file can have strings besides headers also in that case could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==1{val=$0;print} val!=$0' Input_file
```